# Is using one big view better than using two smaller ones (in memory and processing)

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm designing an information system in which most queries involving same sets of tables. The first one requires joining 10 tables (including some LEFT JOIN), and the second one requires joining the 10 tables (and using aggregate functions) with 1 more table. The system uses MySQL.

Which option is better for the system performance and memory usage?

- Using one view involving the 11 tables (all conditions are set outside)
- Using one view involving the 10 tables and using join outside for the other table.
- Using one view involving the 10 tables and another view joining the view and the other table (aggregated).
- other options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views in MySQL are not materialized, so the performance and memory footprint of a view largely depends on the underlying query.  That being said, if you have the need for two views running different (though perhaps slightly similar) queries, I recommend just using two different views.

Regarding the performance of the two views, you should focus on the underlying queries.  This brings in concepts such as indices and normalization, both of which can be important for making a query perform well.